# Saddle points, Nodes and Edges definitions

Tags: image-processing, software-implementation

I am working on some algorithm implementation, however being new to image processing, I have some questions about some of the definitions used.
UPDATE: for those asking for more information, this is the RELEVANT information stated in the paper.

"Step 4: Centerline Computation
Our implementation of the centerline extraction is based on the Distance Transform with thinning as post-processing step as proposed by niblack. The result is a binary mask image g with a centerline thickness of 1, which corresponds to the undirected edge image graph." Then :

- They(in the paper) keep on mentioning a node without prior definition, this means a `true`point with 2 other `true`neighbors(out of 8). Am I right ? (this is the general definition of a node pixel)
- They define an Edge being the distance between two adjacent nodes where the distance between them is $\leq \sqrt2 $. What do they mean by that exactly ?
- Last they define saddle points being `node pixels` with the connected edge length has to be $\geq 3$. I don't know what they mean by that

Update: 
Paper: ROCHADE: Robust Checkerboard Advanced Detection for Camera Calibration

I would like someone having more experience than I do to guide me through these definitions. I can not post the algorithm paper online due to copyright.

Comment: Usually when someone is citing an article it is good to mention it. This ensures getting best possible answer...

Comment: @jojek sorry my bad I thought i did mention it

Comment: @jojek did you find anything ? I really need to understand this because then I know what to do instead of guessing aimlessly.

Comment: It will be hard for anyone to give you answers as we can not access the paper, nor did you explained the problem and the context in details.

Comment: @BálintFodor I have added some more information. This is the relevant part and more information is not provided. Hopefully it is helpful